# Coping with "string contains null byte" sent from users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have an API controller that receives information about a media file's path and id3 tags, and saves them to an Active Record instance, using PostgreSQL/Rails.

Sometimes however the user sends strings such as:

```
"genre"=>"Hip-Hop\u0000Hip-Hop/Rap"
```

and Rails/Postgres aren't exactly happy about that when trying to persist on `save`:

```
An ArgumentError occurred in internals#receive:

 string contains null byte
 activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1172:in `send_query_prepared'
```

How can I clean this string in Ruby to completely remove null bytes?

Comment: It looks like you're receiving text in a UTF-16 encoding. Instead of trying to "clean it up", I'd recommend confirming this with the sender and, if that's the case, use Ruby's Encoding to convert the text to UTF-8. Willy-nilly stripping of the character won't help if it's occurring on other diacritics. Also, both Ruby and PostgreSQL can be upset if you try to store a string encoded one way into a field defined for another type of encoding, so you'll need to be thorough.

Comment: unfortunately users are all around the world and I cannot ask them to change up this stuff, so the fix must be server side, even because this data is sent by our and third party applications.

Comment: It's possible to check a string to see if it's possible to determine its encoding. Sometimes you can get lucky and get a string that is actually all one encoding, which makes it easy to get where you're going. Sometimes you get a string that contains multiple encodings and then have to code for that, but how is left for you to figure out. Asking people to change to you isn't likely to happen unless they need your API/service badly. This is a very gnarly rabbit-hole to fall into and it can devolve into a very tricky situation.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `gsub` method on `String` is probably suitable. You can just do `string.gsub("\u0000", '')` to get rid of them.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-gsub

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `string.delete("\u0000")`?

Comment: No that would work fine too, so would `string.tr`. In fact `tr` and delete are both more appropriate than `gsub` in this case

Answer (score 3):

The `String.delete` method is a better choice because it performs better than both `String.tr` and `String.gsub`; as long as you are replacing with an empty string there is never a reason to choose tr or gsub over delete.

```
"Hip-Hop\u0000Hip-Hop/Rap".delete("\u0000")
# => "Hip-HopHip-Hop/Rap"
```

However, in this case, the string does not make sense with the null character simply deleted, and should probably be replaced with a space (or other delimiting character), so we are back to gsub. But please note that "\u0000" is not visible, so generally a deletion makes sense.

```
"Hip-Hop\u0000Hip-Hop/Rap".tr("\u0000", " ")
# => "Hip-Hop Hip-Hop/Rap"
```

AppSignal has a [nice blog post](https://blog.appsignal.com/2019/08/20/clean-up-strings.html) detailing and profiling various string replacement methods.

Answer (score 0):

With [ActionDispatch::Http::Paramters](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb#L37), we can define a new parser for a given MIME type.

So we can add this code to an initializer to override the default `:json` parser to get rid of the [null char](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) in the json values.

```rb
# ex: config/initializers/mime_types.rb

original_parsers = ActionDispatch::Request.parameter_parsers
json_parser = -> (raw_post) {
  data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(raw_post)
  data.is_a?(Hash) ? data.deep_transform_values { |v| v.respond_to?(:delete) ? v.delete("\u0000") : v } : { _json: data }
}
new_parsers = original_parsers.merge(json: json_parser)
ActionDispatch::Request.parameter_parsers = new_parsers
```

*Caution*: not sure about the performance here, doing a `deep_transform_values` on every json request to the app may be costly. Also, other MIME type accepted by your app using `JSON.parse` (like `:jsonapi`) may need to be defined.

**Edit**: Another way to fix that is to use the [normalizes](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Normalization.html) method in your model. You can do in your model for example:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  normalizes :genre, with: ->(str) { str&.delete("\u0000") }
end
```