# What does a null character in a Twitter handle name look like?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, twitter

I’m testing out a download script I wrote and I came across a really weird Twitter handle name. In my script I have this line:

`@logger.debug("Processing #{_twitter_user.screen_name}")`

And I got this output in my log:

`DEBUG -- : Processing  L a c i L o u 7 7`

This handle causes my script to crash with the following error msg:

`C:/Ruby/23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:625:in 'exec_prepared': string contains null byte (ArgumentError)`

I put a put statement in the script and I got: `\u0000L\u0000a\u0000c\u0000i\u0000L\u0000o\u0000u\u00007\u00007`

I’m sure I can figure out how to handle processing null chars; I’d still love to see other people’s solutions. Question is: what does the handle look like in Twitter/URL? I tried simply inserting the handle string from the log output into the URL and I got a Page Doesn’t Exist error. It seems the logger simply replaced `\u0000` with spaces and that totally changes the handle name.

Comment: Can you share the link to that user's Twitter page?

Comment: I can't. That's the problem. If I simply put in `https://twitter.com/  L a c i L o u 7 7` that won't work.

Comment: Supposedly the null char is represented by `%00` in a URL; I tried that (`https://twitter.com/%00L%00a%00c%00i%00L%00o%00u%007%007`) and it totally didn't work.

Comment: `_twitter_user.screen_name.delete("\u0000")`

Comment: @bo-oz I think you've got the right answer. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29320369/2892779

Comment: If this is an encoding issue, then stripping the null bytes is a hack, and you're better off resolving the encoding issue. If you're downloading the handle as bytes, and then converting the bytes to a string, that will not work. When the download is done, there should be a match between the encoding provided by the API and the encoding assumed by the software receiving it.

Comment: If you're doing this in Ruby, then you may be able to call `twitter_id.force_encoding('UTF-8')` to fix it. Or, trying the same with 'UTF-16'.

Comment: that lookis a lot like `'UTF32-BE` mis-interpreted as `UTF16`